# Check if a user's browser can render given file extension as media

Tags: php, html, browser, web

Is there any way (preferably in PHP) to check if a user's browser is able to render a given file extension as an image, video, or audio inside the browser?

I'm using this for a sort of gallery that can display any type of file in a given directory, but if the file isn't able to be rendered as media, it'll instead show up as a box with the file extension inside it as text.

Comment: Nope. The `Accept` header is probably the closest you will come to something like this, but it does not necessarily tell you what the browser supports.

Comment: You may listen to the `error` event of `<img>`, `<audio>`, `<video>` in JS.